# load JavaScript to partial post back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

just I have problem when loading JavaScript. when first page load it will work fine  but when the user click next page it will not work Just ask is their is away to load this function when user click Next or  Previous? Note: I tried to used pageLoad but no use?

```
$.each($(".resource-download"), function () {
    var fileExtension = getFileExtension(this.href);
    if (fileExtension == "" || fileExtension != "pdf") {
        $(this).addClass("hideLinke");
    }
});



function getFileExtension(fileURL) {
    if (fileURL.indexOf('.') === -1) { return ""; } //check for no extension
    return fileURL.split('.').pop();
}
```

Comment: What did you try in `Page_Load`? `IsPostBack` or `IsInAsyncPostBack`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is an update panel, you need to use the ScriptManager to invoke the script once again after the postback.

So do this:

```
<script>
    function init(){
         $.each($(".resource-download"), function () {
                var fileExtension = getFileExtension(this.href);
                if (fileExtension == "" || fileExtension != "pdf") {
                    $(this).addClass("hideLinke");
                }
            });

    }
    function getFileExtension(fileURL) {
         if (fileURL.indexOf('.') === -1) { return ""; } //check for no extension
            return fileURL.split('.').pop();
    }
</script>
```

And after the postback, call it again as so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), someScript, @"init();", false);
```